# CppCMS - controller / view code does not work right

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, cppcms

I have the following CppCMS MVC code:

```
void routing_controller()
{
    this->route.username = "My name";
    //this->route.debug_string = to_string(num_active);     // won't work here

    if(request().request_method() == "POST")
    {
        this->route.info.load(context());
        if(this->route.info.validate())
        {
            if(this->route.info.num[0].value() == true)
            {
                this->num_active = 0;
            }
            else if(this->route.info.num[1].value() == true)
            {
                this->num_active = 1;
            }
        }
        this->route.debug_string = to_string(num_active);       // only works here
    }
    render("route", this->route);
}
```

Clicking two buttons on the page affect the variables `route.info.num[0/1].value()`.  I use them to change the global variable `num_active`.  This variable is converted to a string and display on the page (view).

However, it only works if I have the line:

```
this->route.debug_string = to_string(num_active);
```

placed below.  If I place it above, it will not render properly (or `num_active` does not have the right value?).  Could someone tells me why this is happening?  This is not logical anyhow to me.

Comment: Global variables are dangerous. What is the type of `num_active`? What do you mean by "will not render properly?" Can you verify, that you have initialized the variable properly?!

Comment: @hellow, num_active is simply an int.